# Как сделать обработку коллизий для объектов одного класса?

Tags: java, libgdx

```
// array containing the active humans.
public final Array<Human> activeHumans = new Array<Human>();
// object pool.
public final Pool<Human> humanPool = new Pool<Human>() {
    @Override
    protected Human newObject() {
        return new Human(100, 500);
    }
};
```

---

```
@Override
public void update(float dt) {
checkCollisions();
}

public void checkCollisions() {

// human-human collision
    for (Human h1 : activeHumans)
        for (Human h2 : activeHumans)
            if (h1.getRectangle().overlaps(h2.getRectangle())) {
                h1.setX(h1.getX() + 2);
                h2.setX(h2.getX() - 2);
            }
}
```

Вот тут он меня выкидывает с `Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: #iterator() cannot be used nested.`. Если сделать `human-otherObject` или даже

```
for (Human h1 : activeHumans)
        for (Human h2 : activeHumansOther)
```

, то все работает, но, понятно, не с теми, что я хочу (взаимодействуют только `human`-`humanOther`, а мне нужно `human`-`human`). Как сделать так, чтобы работал первый вариант - при столкновении хуманов они расходились в разные стороны?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Цикл `for` в стиле `for each` в Java использует для позиционирования по коллекции итератор.

Цикл `for each` может быть использован для любых объектов, реализующих интерфейс `Iterable<T>`.

Например, цикл:

```
for (Integer item: list) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

эквивалентен этому циклу:

```
for(Iterator<Integer> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Integer item = i.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

По причине использования итератора Вы и получаете исключение:

```
... GdxRuntimeException: #iterator() cannot be used nested.
```

Как вариант решения проблемы, можете использовать обычный цикл `for`:

```
for (int i=0; i<activeHumans.size(); i++) {
    Human h1 = activeHumans.get(i);

    for (int j=0; j<activeHumans.size(); j++) {
        Human h2 = activeHumans.get(j);

        // необходимые действия

    }
}
```

Comment: Хм, возникла следующая проблема - теперь h1 и h2 он считает одним и тем же.  <br/> `for (int i=0; i<activeHumans.size(); i++) {
    Human h1 = activeHumans.get(i);

    for (int j=0; j<activeHumans.size(); j++) {
        Human h2 = activeHumans.get(j);

       if (h1 != h2) 
                if (h1.getRectangle().overlaps(h2.getRectangle())) {
                    h1.setX(h1.getX() + 2);

    }
}` и тут, при пересечении фигур, обе движутся на `getX() + 2`

Comment: @Krem Soda, Попробуйте сравнивать не объекты, а индексы: `if (i != j)`.

Comment: Сравнивал только индексы, сравнивал 'activeHumans.get(i) != activeHumans.get(j)', добавлял после этого '.get(i).getRectangle()' - то же самое. Если не делать этого сравнения, то при появлении хумана он сразу начинает двигаться, а при сравнении хуманы начинают двигаться только при соприкосновении (тоже пытался сделать вместо 'h1' 'activeHumans.get(i).getRectangle().x += 2' - все равно движутся оба). Программа делает ровно то, что я ей говорю, значит, что-то я ей говорю неправильно, но не могу понять, что именно

Comment: Вот что нужно было сделать! `for (int j=i+1; j<activeHumans.size(); j++) ` (дополнение к принятому ответу)